# Understanding TLC's finite map library

Tags: coq, tlc

I'm trying to use [TLC](https://github.com/charguer/tlc)'s finite maps to model heaps in separation logic, after going through Separation Logic Foundations. It's quite different from the [finite map library](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/LibSepFmap.html) used there though. For example, I'm not sure why simple facts like the following cannot be proved (extracted from a bigger theorem to debug).

```
Lemma u_empty_l : forall A B (h:map A B),
  \{} \u h = h.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply union_empty_l. (* this works *)
Qed.

Lemma u_empty_r : forall A B (h:map A B),
  h \u \{} = h.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply union_empty_r. (* why does this fail? *)
Abort.
```

```
Errors:
In environment
A : Type
B : Type
h : map A B
Unable to unify "forall x : ?T, x \u \{} = x" with "h \u \{} = h".;
```

If I try to leave the forall in the goal:

```
Lemma u_empty_r : forall A B (h:map A B),
  h \u \{} = h.
Proof.
  intros A B.
  apply union_empty_r.
Qed.
```

```
Errors:
Applied theorem does not have enough premises.;
```

The library is also missing simple lemmas like `disjoint_empty_l`, and tactics for map reasoning (`disjoint`) like in SLF.

I feel like I'm missing something about how the library is supposed to be used. Or is it just that TLC doesn't contain all the separation logic stuff from SLF? As a beginner should I just stick to the SLF library?